# Strapi: Custom Fields not showing after installing plugin

Tags: strapi

i discovered a problem with custom fields. I installed the multi select plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-multi-select) and its showing up in the admin dashboard via general -> plugins.

In the content type builder when i want to create a new field and i click on "custom" the multi select field is not showing up for selection. I tried it with different other custom field plugins and none is working.

I sadly don't get any error, maybe someone here experienced the same issue

my dependencies looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@strapi/plugin-graphql": "4.5.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.5.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.5.0",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.5.0",
    "better-sqlite3": "7.4.6",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.6",
    "deep-rename-keys": "^0.2.1",
    "deep-rename-keys-ts": "^1.0.1",
    "geographiclib": "^1.52.2",
    "geographiclib-geodesic": "^2.0.0",
    "graphql-type-json": "^0.3.2",
    "nexus": "^1.3.0",
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "strapi-plugin-country-select": "^1.0.0",
    "strapi-plugin-multi-select": "^1.1.0",
    "strapi-utils": "^3.6.11"
  }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5):

You need to rebuild your strapi after plugin installation. This is the same for all plugins in Strapi CMS please go to your strapi folder and run

`yarn build` then `yarn develop`

Answer (score 0):

So i found a solution to solve the symptoms of the problem, not the root cause.

It somehow has to to with a webpack error i'm experiencing when building the project:

```
No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'
```

Well there were inputs, which is kinda strange.

After trying to fix the upper bug and deleting different directories *`.cache .tmp .dist .node_modules`*, `package-lock.json`, and even the project folder itself. I tried to re-clone, re-install and re-build.

Nothing seemed to help **EXCEPT** to clone it into another directory than i usually store my repos.

My webpack error was gone and i could install and use the plugins without hassle!

I don't know if someone ever will experience the same error, but this solved the symptoms and i could get back to work ;)

Comment: If someone can explain what might have caused this error please do :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, once installed, you need to run `npm run build` before `npm run develop`.
Then, when selecting the field, you must choose custom instead of default.
All fields added with a plugin are in custom (multi-select, uuid, etc.).